# Ecobee3 Setup and furnace only has W G R

Tags: furnace, thermostat

My existing thermostat has 4 wires (missing C) so I'm attempting to use the Power Extender Kit (PEK) at the furnace control board. Only problem is, I only have 3 wires that are obviously labelled at the furnace (W, G, R). I have central air and I'd like to get my Ecobee3 setup if possible. Help.
[image: furnace[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXRAm.jpg)

Comment: Can you get us a wiring diagram for your furnace?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to see from the picture but if you look at the bottom 2 terminals on the transformer the one on the right is red and the one on the left is kind of blue/lavender. Red is typically “R” and the other one is typically the “C”. The top two wires are line voltage, don’t mess with those.